# Can I use a variable for n in Small(array,n) that increments inside a loop? Maybe a better method?

Tags: vba

I'm trying find the smallest to next smallest value from a range and return the cell address for each value in order from smallest to largest until the largest is found. As an example...if A1:I1 contained an integer from 1-9 in a random order with no duplicates, How can I find the cell address of the cell with 1, then cell address with the value 2, etc. until the cell address of 9 was found? I hoped I could use SMALL and increment n with a variable in a loop but get an error. When I step through this routine "smaller = Error 2029" when  SmallCount is used in the SMALL function. If I replace Smallcount with an actual integer there's no issues. Any assistance is appreciated....here's basically where I'm at......

```
Sub NotWorking()

    LoopCount = 9
    SmallCount = 1

    Do While LoopCount <> "0"

        smaller = [CELL("address",INDEX(A1:I1,MATCH(SMALL(A1:I1,SmallCount), A1:I1,0)))]

        LoopCount = LoopCount - 1
        SmallCount = SmallCount + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA has a much more convenient way of referring to individual cells -- several of them, actually. One is the Cells function, that allows you to use variables for the row and column number directly: Cells(2,3) is the same as "C2" (row 2, column 3). Instead of literal numbers, you can use variables or expressions.

Comment: Are all of the values unique?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about your goal but you may try this code:

```
Sub HopefullyWorking()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim col As Variant

    With Range("A1:I1") ' <--| reference your range
        For i = 1 To .Count '<--| loop from 1 to referenced range cells number
            col = Application.Match(WorksheetFunction.Small(.Cells, i), .Cells, 0) '<--| try finding current "small" number in referenced cells
            If Not IsError(col) Then MsgBox "Number " & i & " found at position " & col
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```